# Is it possible not to use onReceive command when receiving data through i2c?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c

I understand that when trying to receive data through i2c I can use the following code in arduino :

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(0x04);                // join i2c bus with address #8
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Serial.begin(9600);           // start serial for output
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
}

void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  while (1 < Wire.available()) { // loop through all but the last
    char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
    Serial.print(c);         // print the character
  }
  int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
  Serial.println(x);         // print the integer
}
```

But what if I don't want to use the onReceive command at void.setup and receive using a function like the following code:

```
void receiveData() { 
  Wire.begin(0x04);
  while(Wire.available()) {               
      if(x==4) { x=0;}
      data[x]=Wire.read();
      x++;
    }
}
```

I want to do this because I have to read a sensor and simultaneously receive an array from a raspberry pi. 
Is this doable?

BTW I am using an arduino nano and raspberry pi 3 and the sensor is MPU6050.